# Can I copy tracks in Pro Tools without copying audio regions?

Tags: pro-tools

Can I copy tracks in ProTools without copying the audio regions on those tracks but still preserving the input, output, and pan settings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe when you do "Duplicate Track", you have the option of what to duplicate; you can choose to not duplicate the regions, but preserve everything else…

Don't have it in front of me to test, but I remember seeing those options last time I duped a track.

Comment: Good call, I just kinda blew through that dialog with the defaults.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use "duplicate track" dialog for this.
Alt+D if i'm not mistaken although i usually mess these ones up when I'm not actually working